# How to handle incoming CNAME records and point to the specified URL?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, dns, cname

I have looked everywhere for something on this but can't seem to find anything.

After setting up the CNAME record of a domain (i.e. `user_domain.com`) to point to my own `example.com`, what would be the next step? How would I get it to point to `example.com`?

I believe that I will need to do something on my end in order to handle these domains but I can't find any tutorials on how to do so.

The error that is received when visiting `user_domain.com` is:

- user_domain.com’s server DNS address could not be found.

For the record, I am using Ubuntu, Apache and PHP. Would something need to be done to the .htaccess file?

**CNAME**

- www             example.com

**Overall**

- I am trying to let users point their own domain to `example.com`
- What would be the next step after setting up the CNAME record?

I would appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either have to:

- Configure your Apache with name-based virtual hosts and have it listen explicitly for the new domain via the [`ServerAlias`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#serveralias) directive.

Or:

- Configure your Apache for IP-based hosts. It will serve the example.com content for whatever domain name is pointed at it.

Or:

- Configure your Apache with name-based virtual hosts and have it listen implicitly for the new domain by making sure example.com is the first vhost listed in the config. This will make example.com the "default" service for IP-based requests. (Not 100% sure about this one, but this is how I recall Apache behaving.)

Comment: Thanks for the response! What would I have to do to configure it to accept any domain pointed to it rather than manually specifying each domain?

Comment: Option #2 or #3.

Comment: Option 2, or perhaps whichever would be the most efficient/easiest to configure

Comment: Option #2 is probably the most efficient, but note if you have any other name-based vhosts already defined on the same IP, they'll break.

Comment: I have two domains pointing to the same server, is there any way around this?

Comment: Yeah, option #3.

Comment: How would I get that to work? example.com is currently the first VHost, what would be the next step?

Comment: If my memory of Apache is correct, you're done. Point another domain at that same IP and see what happens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141910/discussion-between-osman-and-alex-howansky).